# Timestamp problem in mediawiki after upgrade to 1.32

Tags: php, sql, timestamp, mediawiki, sql-timestamp

after update from 1.28 to 1.32:

link of 1.32  :http://wikijoo.ir/32

link of 1.28:http://wikijoo.ir

```
1.32.0
PHP 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.5 (apache2handler)
MySQL   5.7.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
ICU 55.1
Lua 5.1.5
MediaWiki internal error.
```

Original exception:

```
Wikimedia\Assert\ParameterAssertionException from line 63 of /var/www/html/32/vendor/wikimedia/assert/src/Assert.php: Bad value for parameter $row->rev_timestamp: must be a valid timestamp
```

Backtrace:

```
#0 /var/www/html/32/includes/Revision/RevisionStoreRecord.php(73): Wikimedia\Assert\Assert::parameter(boolean, string, string)

#1 /var/www/html/32/includes/Revision/RevisionStore.php(1794): MediaWiki\Revision\RevisionStoreRecord->__construct(Title, User, CommentStoreComment, stdClass, MediaWiki\Revision\RevisionSlots, boolean)

#2 /var/www/html/32/includes/Revision/RevisionStore.php(2757): MediaWiki\Revision\RevisionStore->newRevisionFromRow(stdClass, integer, Title)

#3 /var/www/html/32/includes/Revision.php(1308): MediaWiki\Revision\RevisionStore->getKnownCurrentRevision(Title, integer)

#4 /var/www/html/32/includes/page/WikiPage.php(744): Revision::newKnownCurrent(Wikimedia\Rdbms\DatabaseMysqli, Title, integer)

#5 /var/www/html/32/includes/page/WikiPage.php(766): WikiPage->loadLastEdit()

#6 /var/www/html/32/includes/page/WikiPage.php(638): WikiPage->getRevision()

#7 /var/www/html/32/includes/libs/objectcache/WANObjectCache.php(1277): WikiPage->{closure}(boolean, integer, array, NULL)

#8 /var/www/html/32/includes/libs/objectcache/WANObjectCache.php(1150): WANObjectCache->doGetWithSetCallback(string, integer, Closure, array)

#9 /var/www/html/32/includes/page/WikiPage.php(647): WANObjectCache->getWithSetCallback(string, integer, Closure)

#10 /var/www/html/32/includes/page/WikiPage.php(269): WikiPage->getContentModel()

#11 /var/www/html/32/includes/page/WikiPage.php(256): WikiPage->getContentHandler()

#12 /var/www/html/32/includes/actions/Action.php(98): WikiPage->getActionOverrides()

#13 /var/www/html/32/includes/actions/Action.php(156): Action::factory(string, WikiPage, RequestContext)

#14 /var/www/html/32/includes/MediaWiki.php(155): Action::getActionName(RequestContext)

#15 /var/www/html/32/includes/MediaWiki.php(777): MediaWiki->getAction()

#16 /var/www/html/32/includes/MediaWiki.php(517): MediaWiki->main()

#17 /var/www/html/32/index.php(42): MediaWiki->run()

#18 {main}
```

OR

when is use rebuildtex.php in putty show this error:

```
Clearing searchindex table...Done

Rebuilding index fields for 2042149538 pages...

[671f7d80f09b99cf7a1c40b2] [no req]   Wikimedia\Assert\ParameterAssertionExcepti                                                                                        on from line 63 of /var/www/html/32/vendor/wikimedia/assert/src/Assert.php: Bad                                                                                         value for parameter $row->rev_timestamp: must be a valid timestamp
```

Comment: Sounds like invalid data in the database. Valid timestamps are strings of the form YYYYDDMMhhmmss (usually; it might depend on your configuration).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you use solar-hijri date (خورشیدی) format?. I guess that this format is no longer supported in the latest versions of Mediawiki. This error [occurs](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/REL1_32/php/RevisionArchiveRecord_8php_source.html) when it check each row in `Revision` table, and if it's not validated, it throw this exception.

To check if the problem is with the database, run this query:

```
select rev_timestamp from revision limit 10;
```

Then check the timestamps in the output. If the `rev_timestamp` is not at this format *20190101235900*, then this means that you need to update all `rev_timestamp` fields in this table, with the exact format supported by Mediawiki.

Comment: Thank you for answering what is green in maintenance of SQL and it works correctly
The TIMESTAMP example format is as follows:
3230313030393137323334343431

In the past and in version 1.28, this has been the case, and it has not been a problem either.

There is a problem that I can not properly search in the encyclopedia, and after the execution
php rebuildtextindex.php

The error below:

Comment: The error below:
Clearing the search index table ... Done
Rebuilding index fields for 2042149588 pages ...
[9ba53f60218589c0d66621a7] [no req] Wikimedia \ Assert \ ParameterAssertionException from line 63 of /var/www/html/33/33/vendor/wikimedia/assert/src/Assert.php: Bad value for parameter $ row-> rev_timestamp: black without a valid timestamp
Backtrace: